# onFocus does not remove value input text box

Tags: jquery, html, search, input, input-field

If I use this: `<input class="search" type="text" id="input" onfocus="this.value=''" />` and I write for example: `arduino` and it searches for everything with the text `arduino` and after that I click on somewhere else on the webpage and then click on the input field again, the text clears out as it should, but I have to `backspace` once on my keyboard, to clear the results for `arduino` and show everything.

Why and how can I fix this? Thanks

[jsfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/F4LLCON/dErda/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger the keyup handler onfocus:

http://jsfiddle.net/dErda/1/

```
$('#input').on('focus',function(){
        this.value='';
        $(this).keyup();
    });
```

Comment: Awesome! It works thanks, I'll mark this as the solution in 6 min

Comment: Another question, can you help me out with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389405/remove-icon-for-input-with-css-and-jquery thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to clear search and show everything back:

```
$("input[type=text]").focus(function(){
  $(this).val('');    
    $('.input').hide();
     $("ul.filter li").show();
});
```