# remove icon for input with css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, search, button, input

I am trying to get this to work but it doesn't.

I have removed my code for cleanup and here is the [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/F4LLCON/wQ7Rq/)

I am trying to create the remove button that removes the input and also resets the search list

```
 -----------------------
|                  | x | <- remove icon inside the input box
 -----------------------     
or 
 ----------------------- ----------
|                      | | All    |  <- all button outside the input box
 ----------------------- ----------
```

I can't manage to get the code to work e.g. reset the search results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it is what you are looking for...

Use HTML5 input type search:

```
<input class="search clearable" type="search" id="input"/>
```

Then add handler click for input:

```
$('#input').on('click',function(){
        if(this.value === "" ) //case when user reset the input by clicking button
            $(this).keyup();
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wQ7Rq/1/)